# Does anything else go when "auf" does not?

Tags: grammaticality

> Question: Um wie viel Uhr stehst du am Montag auf?
>
> Answer: Hm, Am Montag stehe ich um sechs auf.
>
> Question: Wann frühstückst du am Sonntag?
>
> Answer: Am Sonntag frühstücke ich um zehn Uhr.

Is it

> Am Sonntag frühstücke ich um zehn Uhr

or perhaps it should be

> Am Sonntag frühstücke ich um zehn

I'm trying to follow the pattern from the 1st Q/A but *auf* doesn't seem to fit on the 2nd Q/A.

Comment: You seem to be mistaken about the function of "auf". It's part of the separable verb "aufstehen".

Answer (score 3):

Both work, the latter is a bit more formal.

> Am Sonntag frühstücke ich um zehn Uhr.
> Am Sonntag frühstücke ich um zehn.

It's quite common to omit units (that formally go with numbers) in colloquial talk when it is clear what is meant.

> Der Kleiderschrank ist 2,50 breit und 1,80 hoch.
> Wir treffen uns um fünf vor acht.
> Ein Käsebrötchen kostet eins sechzig.

Comment: So may I also omit `auf` and say `Hm, Am Montag stehe ich um sechs`?

Comment: @KcFnM: no, "aufstehen" and "stehen" are two different verbs with different meanings, so you cannot omit the "auf".

Comment: So the full version of the first answer is *Hm, Am Montag stehe ich um sechs Uhr auf.* The difference between including or omitting Uhr/o'clock is the about same in German and English.